# Is there any best way to migrate existing tables without foreign keys to Laravel 5 with Eloquent?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, mariadb

I am currently testing laravel 5.2 with MariaDB 10.0, and love this framework. I would like to migrate some part of existing web app (custom accounting web application) to Laravel 5.2. but there are some issues to migrate my current web application to Laravel.

**(1) Current database doesn't use Foreign key**
As I read the Laravel manual, to use the Eloquent ORM( not Query builder), using Foreign key is mandatory as far as I understand. but existing database doesn't use Foreign key at all.

**(2) Current Database structure doesn't fit to Laravel**
As I understand Laravel requrired their own styled table structure although they allow some overriding but not everything. but as I review my database, it needs a lot of modification to fit the laravel style.

In summary, what I want to do is migrating some of existing tables and develope laravel web application using Eloquent, not Query builder.

I am looking forward to your great opinions and advices.

Answer (score 1):

**(1)** That's not true. Using foreign keys is not mandatory. Relationships will be loaded using convention rules, which has to do with point 2. Although using them is recommended. I screwed up some apps because foreign keys were not created in MySQL because the default engine didn't support them. I didn't notice until to late.

**(2)** Laravel is Convention over Configuration, that means, it works so much better if your DB matches Laravel conventions. However, I don't understand why not running all the migrations? Unused tables can still live in the database. Just don't use them in Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use [Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships) and [protect](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/268000/should-i-use-foreign-keys-in-my-database-if-i-use-laravel) DB integrity, you need to set foreign keys. Alternatively you could use [Query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries).

To use tables with custom names, you can add this to every model to force [Laravel use existing table name](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions):

```
protected $table = 'table_name';
```

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent is pretty flexible. I used Laravel 5.0 Eloquent on an existing, all custom php application, and it worked great.

The biggest challenge I faced was figuring out how to create migrations. I ended up using [phpmig](https://github.com/davedevelopment/phpmig) to create and execute the migrations. And I was able to load Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager inside the migrations, so I could use Laravel's Schema Builder.

Using migrations you could add foreign key indexes to existing columns. You may have to change the column definition to match the foreign column.